# Google Places Api Daily Limit Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, google-places-api

Hi I have made an app and enable Google Places api for that project.
I create a project on google developer portal and add the key in to my iOS app After that I start to send request to google Api and My search Works very well as I also know that google has per day request limit on each Api

Now today I send Max. 30 request and after that from google Api I was given error that your daily quota is reached which is 1k request / day.

I did not find any solution on any where Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request more quota:

https://developers.google.com/places/uplift

If you reached the quota while testing your app, make sure that you have used the developer key for that purpose.

Comment: I did only 30 to 40 request for testing and then google says you cross your limit of 1k/day I did not understand

Comment: Investigate your code. Seems to be more than you intent to do

Comment: only one tester can send max. 300 to 400 request but I did not understand about 1k / day I just crossed

Comment: @runDOSrun i will have to make my app live and i have used Google places Api for searching places so how will i use it free of cost without any limit

Comment: @runDOSrun then what u do can u tell me

Comment: @DilipTiwari click on the link and see pricing. Everything is explained. It's either quota or payment.

Comment: @runDOSrun i m a developer so it can be done through our side or client side

Answer (score 0):

What kind of **Search** are you using?

Some types of searches *cost* more than others.

For example, one of the autocomplete search types, **Text Search**, has a **10x multiplier**. (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

Make sure that you look at the usage limits specified for each API/service you are using.

Additionally, if you are looking at your online dashboard you can see the real-time number of requests that have been made / are being made to each API/service by project. This can help debug when these requests may be being made and how many are occurring per call you believe to be making.